# Hide price and add to cart button on product page only

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I’m using Datafeedr to show price comparison sets on a product page. The price comparison table opens up dynamically once the page is loaded. But because I want people to follow the link to the cheapest store that offers that product I really have no use for each imported product to show it’s own price. That price could be higher than the prices that are shown in the comparison table and the link of the button would then send the visitor to the wrong store. I have a plugin that turns of the prices and add to cart buttons, but it also turns of the prices on the category pages. And I do want the prices to show there because on the category pages people can filter the prices or set a price range. Can someone tell me with which snippets I can leave the prices in the category pages, but hide them on the single product pages and also how to hide the add to cart button? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove price and add to cart button on the product page Only

```
// Remove Price from the product page
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

// Remove Add to cart form from the product page
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

Comment: Hey that is awsome. It does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries, you can mark this answer as accepted.